# Why Chrome doesn't display POST request at dev tools network tab after preflight request?

Tags: node.js, cors, graphql, react-apollo, prisma-graphql

I have a React Apollo Client running at http://localhost:7777
And a Graphql-Yoga server running at http://localhost:4444

When I execute mutations via react-apollo, they work as intended on the backend.

when I execute the mutation via Firefox the (preflight request + post request) are logged at Chrome DevTools.

Though, when I execute the mutation via Chrome, only preflight request is logged on the DevTools.

The mutations happens as intended in both cases, I'm wondering why google chrome doesn't show the POST request at its network's tab.

Illustrative image:

[image: error]

*Image URL:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JaUx.png

I already tried to use express cors middleware, but it did hang the server.

#### createServer.js

```
// Graphql Yoga Instantiation function

const { GraphQLServer } = require("graphql-yoga");

const Mutation = require("./resolvers/Mutation");
const Query = require("./resolvers/Query");
const db = require("./db");

function createServer() {
  return new GraphQLServer({
    typeDefs: "./src/schema.graphql",
    resolvers: {
      Mutation,
      Query
    },
    resolverValitaionOptions: {
      requireResolversForResolveType: false
    },
    context: req => ({ ...req, db })
  });
}

module.exports = createServer;
```

#### index.js

The file which starts the server when running `npm run dev`

```
// Server initialization file index.js

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });

const createServer = require("./createServer");
const db = require("./db");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const server = createServer();



//Use express to handle cookies (JWT)
server.express.use(cookieParser());
//Use express to populate current user
server.express.use((req, res, next) => {
  const {
    cookies: { token }
  } = req;

  if (token) {
    const { userId } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.APP_SECRET);
    req.userId = userId;
  }

  next();
});

// Populate each request with the user
server.express.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req;
  const { query } = db;
  if (!userId) return next();

  const user = await query.user(
    { where: { id: userId } },
    "{id, permissions, email, name}"
  );

  req.user = user;

  return next();
});

server.start({
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL // http://localhost:7777
  },
  deets: deets => {
    console.log(`Server is now running on localhost:${deets.port}`);
  }
});
```

I expect to see on Chrome DevTools network tab the post request log the same way it shows on firefox.

Comment: For me, it shows everything in Chrome Devtools. I can see differences in your screenshots. In the Chrome one you are at a section (/items) of the page, and in the dev tools you have marked the filter for XHR calls, while in Firefox you are at the root of your page and don't have any filter in devtools. I don't say that makes the difference... but I'd try the same in both browsers to check... in my Chrome it shows the preflight call before the POST

Comment: @JVLobo Thanks for your comment, I've posted how I fixed the problem.

Have you ever passed through something like that before?

Comment: not really... looks super weird

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the preflight (OPTIONS) request get listed after the actual (GET) request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973978/why-does-the-preflight-options-request-get-listed-after-the-actual-get-reque)

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was an local issue.

I just changed

```
server.start({
  port: 4444,
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL
  },
  deets: deets => {
    console.log(`Server is now running on localhost:${deets.port}`);
  }
});
```

to :

```
const options = {{
  port: 4444,
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL
  },
  deets: deets => {
    console.log(`Server is now running on localhost:${deets.port}`);
  }
}};

server.start(options);
```

And it worked perfectly in both.

Then, I changed it back to and it is still working.

```
server.start(
  {
    port: 4444,
    cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL
    },
    deets: deets => {
      console.log(`Server is now running on localhost:${deets.port}`);
    }
  },
  options
);
```

**IMPORTANT:.** I've rebooted the graphql server several times before and it didn't work as it worked when extracting options to a const. Could this be some sort of caching issue?