# Why does the preflight (OPTIONS) request get listed after the actual (GET) request?

Tags: sorting, cors, google-chrome-devtools, preflight

I am testing out a cross-origin web request. I find that in Chrome, most of the time the preflight OPTION request comes *after* the actual GET request. This is the order as seen in the Network tab of Chrome Developer Tools.

[image]

Shouldn't the OPTION response be first received by the browser before it can decide whether to send the GET request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

The start time (or *initiation time*) of a request corresponds, not to the moment the browser actually *sends* the request, but to the moment the browser *initiates* the request.

### An explanation

According to [Chrome's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#sort_requests),

> By default, the requests in the Requests table are sorted by *initiation time* [and in ascending order].

But *initiation time* does not correspond to the moment when the browser actually sends the request! From the browser's point of view, the actual request is [*initiated/started*](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#sort_requests) (if not *sent*) before the associated preflight request is.

You can view the browser as some intermediary between the client (which initiates the actual request) and the server. The diagram below (borrowed from [elsewhere](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#cors-101)) illustrates the ordering of the preflight and actual requests:

1. The client first *initiates* a cross-origin request (which happens not to be [*simple*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests));
2. The browser *queues* (or "pauses") the actual request and *sends* a preflight request.

[image: CORS-preflight fetch]

You can see that

- the actual request starts (1) *before* the preflight request starts (2), but
- the actual request is *sent* (4), if preflight succeeds of course, and hence ends (6) only *after* the preflight request has ended (3).

### An experiment

1. Open Chrome's DevTools on this very page.
2. Go to the Console tab and execute the following code:

   ```js
   fetch('https://www.example.com', {method: "PUT"})
   ```
3. Go the Network tab. Notice that requests are
   sorted by ascending order of their *start time*.
   Accordingly, the preflight request is at the bottom.
   [image: Sorted by start time]
4. Now right-click on any column header and select *Waterfall* > *End time*. Notice that the the preflight request is now at the top.
   [image: Sorted by end time]